# Time periods clustering

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, regression, cluster-analysis

I have data on international agreements (2123 agreements). I want to perform regression analysis and one of the most important variable to control for is the time period during which the agreement was designed. Agreements in my database are between 1945 and 2017 and it is not like panel data, because each agreement is independant. I want to minimize the number of time periods dummies I will use, while controlling well for this important confounding factor. I was thinking of using a clustering technic to identify my "ideal" time periods. What would be a good way of doing so in R? Do you have any other way of dealing with that kind of problem?

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. As currently stated, your question is to vague to answer. For example, you don't explain any of the data that might be used to cluster the time periods. Also, what code have you already written, and what problem are you encountering with it?

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320216/7828